deflated cubic equation: is there a systematic way to reduce of the Cardano solution?
Let assume the following deflated cubic equation $x^3+6x-20=0$.
The Cardano formula gives as solution $x_c=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{108}+10}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{108}-10}$.
As well as the author of the book where I picked the equation,
my favourite CAS can simplify $x_c$ to $2$. However, I am wondering how they proceeds.

Search on "denest cubic" in this forum.

See here.

If you have reason to believe this simplifies to a rational number then the original equation has a rational root. Using the rational root theorem, you find that $2$ is the only rational root.
More completely, you had $$(x-2)(x^2+2x+10)=0$$ so the other two roots are not real ($-1\pm3i$) and the Cardano number simply must be $2$.
